# Android: Declaring static bitmaps? Yay or nay?

Tags: android, static, bitmap, declaration

Somebody recently commented on my code where I declare the following:

```
private Bitmap splashBackground;
private Bitmap lightDot;
private static Bitmap scaledBackground;
private static Bitmap scaledLightDot;
```

They advised me against declaring satic Bitmaps.

However, I've tried everything and my code doesn't work unless I declare them as static.

Also, "public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)" seems to appear on the official Android Developer site so I'm a bit confused about what I should and shouldn't be doing.

Any pointers would be appreciated - thank you

Edit: For clarification:

When I remove the static from my declaration, then by the time I get to my onDraw() method, the scaled bitmap is null.  (I am creating the scaled bitmap object in an initialise() method and once it's been created, it is valid (ie, not null) - but then seems to become null at onDraw unless I declare it as static.

I am calling my initialise() method from my activity class.

Edit: More code as requested.

My OnCreate method: As you can see, I'm passing my screen height and width over so I can create my scaled bitmaps

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        displaySplashScreen= new SplashScreen(this);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // set View
        setContentView(new SplashScreen(this));
        WindowManager w = getWindowManager();   
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        int width=d.getWidth();
        int height=d.getHeight();
        displaySplashScreen.initialise(width, height);
}
```

My initalise method:

```
 public void initialise(int w, int h)
 {       
     //Get width and height (passed in from Activity)

     vwidth=w;
     vheight=h;

     //Create pre-scaled bitmaps

    scaledBackground = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(splashBackground,  vwidth, vheight, true);
    scaledLightDot = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(lightDot, vwidth, vheight, true);

 }
```

I could add also that if I use a standard variable in the same way (say int number;) and set it in initalise (number = 5;), then number is only equal to 5in my initialise method.  If I log it from onDraw() it will always repeatedly return '0'!!  It's baffling.

Thanks everyone so far, please let me know if more code is required......

Comment: You can call static methods from a non-static context, just not the other way around.  So i'm not sure why those bitmaps need to be static to use createScaledBitmap( ).

Comment: @paul I get a nullPointerException if I remove the static part of the declaration when I'm drawing the object to the canvas. When I create the object in my Initialise() method, it has value, but in my onDraw() method, it's null, I confirmed this using Log.v :-/

Comment: Not sure we have enough info to figure out why thats happening.  Perhaps your initialize( ) method is being called after onDraw( ).

Comment: I'm actually calling my Initialise() method from my activity class so it is definately being call before onDraw() - maybe this is the poroblem? I am just about to put that info into my question as I forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, utilizing `static` for `Bitmap`s is a very bad idea. There are a lot of good reasons for this, mostly having to do with avoiding memory leaks.

> Also, "public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)" seems to appear on the official Android Developer site ...

This is not a `static Bitmap`. This is a method call to a class method. Static does not work the same and the return type (`Bitmap`) is not static. What this means is that the method is static and does not require an instance to be called. It will return a Bitmap to be placed in an appropriate variable of your choice.

> I am calling my `initialise()` method from my activity class.

This statement is quite unhelpful. From *where* in the class is it being called? Is it in `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()`, some other custom method? Where and when you choose to do certain things can have a huge effect as to how successful they are.

> ... but then seems to become null at onDraw unless I declare it as static.

This could be for several possible reasons, and since we don't have any of your code there really isn't a qualified answer. Here are some things to look at.

- This could be because the Activity is getting recreated.
- This could also be because some method that *seems* unrelated is actually getting called. This would probably be somewhere that you are manually setting it to `null`.
- This might be due to improper use of the `createScaledBitmap()` method.
- The Bitmap might be getting recycled due to low memory (this actually happens more often than one would think)

**EDIT: After reviewing your code**

This looks like it may be the culprit. Above, you have...

```
displaySplashScreen= new SplashScreen(this);
```

Below, you add...

```
setContentView(new SplashScreen(this));
```

This means that you are creating ***two*** Splashscreens. One reason why you are getting a null pointer when you are not using `static` may be because further down the line you use...

```
displaySplashScreen.initialise(width, height);
```

But since your contentView is set to a ***new*** SplashScreen, you are not actually utilizing that View. To resolve this, make sure you are talking to the ***same*** view object. I.E.

```
setContentView(displaySplashScreen);
```

This will at least make sure you are looking at the same object. It is possible that you may have to reorganize a bit depending upon what other things are happening. For instance,

```
setContentView(displaySplashScreen);
```

... may have to appear below ...

```
 displaySplashScreen.initialise(width, height);
```

This is something that you might have to toy with, but I don't see anything else that gives any other immediate indication. Be aware that resolving nullpointerexceptions will often result in revealing more errors in code, at first. Stay the course and resolve each in order.

Comment: Thanks @Fuzzical, I will post some of my code. Apologies, my initialise() method is being called from onCreate() in my activity class.

Comment: That was it! No idea why I put that in there lol, thank you @Fuzzical (names aren't being flagged like they normally are for some reason) - Pang also suggested this, I will accept your answer as you explained it very well and I understand exactly why this was causing the problem now.  Thanks, this has been driving me nuts for ages.

Comment: This answer doesn't have much information on why declaring bitmaps static is a bad idea, which is what most people who google this question are looking for.

Comment: @CleverLittleMonkey : It states right away... memory leaks. In addition, the user needed solving a code problem, which was the core issue. The question was based on a misunderstanding which was also directly addressed. Finally, the code problem was solved. To go into details which are lengthy and out of the scope of the answer would be ill advised.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
    // set View
    setContentView(new SplashScreen(this));        // This line is wrong.
```

Should be this:

```
    // set View
    setContentView(displaySplashScreen);        // displaySplashScreen is created earlier.
```

You are created two instances of `SplashScreen`. You should keep using the same instance.

Comment: Thanks @Pang, this was the problem - someone else also suggested this, I have accepted their answer as their explanation was a little more detailed and easier for me to understand why this was causing the issue, and SO only let's me chose one answer, but thanks very much. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for nay,
this one is a static variable

```
private Bitmap splashBackground;
private Bitmap lightDot;
private static Bitmap scaledBackground;
private static Bitmap scaledLightDot;
```

and this one is a static method

```
public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, 
     int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)
```

static variable is usually declared for a constant and the variable belongs to class not object as an example if you have a class

```
public class car {
      private static colorOfCar;
      private numberOfDoor;
}
```

let's say you have a class car and have 2 variable colorOfCar and numberOfDoor when you create an object porsche and ferrari from car class if you change the number of door it's OK the numberOfDoor in your porsche object and ferrari object will be different, but if you change the colorOfCar both porsche object and ferrari object colorOfCar will be changed because the colorOfCar is a static object that belong to the class not the object.

I hope you understand my explanation. If you find my answer helping you please vote and accept my answer and if you have any other question feel free to ask in the comment, thank you :)

Comment: Thank you @NAYOSO I do understand.  However, what I can't understand is (see my comment above) if I remove the static from my declaration, then although my object gets created, when it gets to my onDraw() method it's null and I get a nullPointerException - if I put the static back in, everything is OK, any idea how I can make this non-static while allowing it to run?  Any help greatly appreciated. :-)

Comment: I think that'll be another question, please post another question with  more code (in the class where you have the error) and log cat error :) I'll try to answer your question

Comment: Thanks @NAYOSO - appreciate your help, I have actually said in my question that this is the problem though, I will edit the main question though to make it clearer.  thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, it seems you are using your view is being created more than once.  Maybe in two instances of the view, or maybe the same view being recreated (Activity restarting).  In the first time around, initialize() is being called before onDraw(), making your static Drawable initialized and valid.  The second time around, onDraw() is running *before* initialize() (which works when Drawable is static).  This is most likely due to you inflating the view and calling initialize() afterwards (this means the view is already in the layout).  i.e.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); //the view is added to layout, onDraw() may be called
  MyView view = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.myview);
  view.initialize();  //initializing the drawable from null
  //no guarentee that initialize was called before onDraw()
}
```

This runs ok when your Drawable is static because when the second view is drawn, *it is using the same Drawable which was initialized by the first view*.  When you remove the static, you need to make sure initialize is always called before onDraw().

Instead of calling initialize() from your activity, why not invoke it from the View's constructor?  I often use the following pattern:

```
public class MyView extends View {

  private Bitmap splashBackground;
  private Bitmap lightDot;
  private Bitmap scaledBackground;
  private Bitmap scaledLightDot;

  public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  public MyView(AttributeSet attr, Context context) {
    super(attr, context);
    //parse attr for xml attributes
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
    splashBackground = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash_background);
    lightDot = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_dot);
    scaledLightDot = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(lightDot, getDPI(32), getDPI(32), false);
  }

  public void onSizeChanged(int width, int height) {
    scaledBackground =  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (splashBackground, width, height, false);
  }

  /**
   * Convert pixel value to device independent pixels (DPI)
   * @params pixels  Value for pixel size for MDPI screens
   */
  private int getDPI(int pixels) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, pixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
  }

  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //non-static drawables are guaranteed to be not-null
    canvas.draw(scaledBackground, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.draw(scaledLightDot, 10, 10, null);
  }
}
```

You'll be all set

Comment: Hi @mark.kedziedski, you are correct, that is how I am calling initialise() - the only problem from calling it in the constructor is that 1) I am actually passing the devices resolution from onCreate into initialise (see code - I will update) and I'm not sure how to do that any other way, and secondly I only want initialise these values once (It will contain other values like sprite X and Y co-ordinates). So when the home key is pressed and the app re-started, it doesn't re-initialise everything. PS Sorry, I'n not sure why your name isn't being flagged correctly

Comment: (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)

Comment: The view won't get recreated when the Activity resumes, only in onCreate